# TesstNg parallel execution concatenate the input test data in one browser

Tags: selenium, testng

I have two test cases in a class.when run parallel using TestNg it concatenate all  the test data and put it one browser While the other browser is empty.

selenium Version: 3.8.21
Firefox: Latest
testng: 6.8.21

Below is the Code
[image]

```
package cli;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test1 {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("@BeforeMethod: The annotated method will be run before each test method.");

    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        driver = jenkinHub.hub();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]")).sendKeys("Testing");
        System.out.println("This is current Url " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        driver.quit();

    }

    @Test
    public void NotTesting() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        driver = jenkinHub.hub();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]")).sendKeys("Not Testing");
        System.out.println("This is current Url " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

xmlFile

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Regression Suite" verbose="1" parallel="methods" thread-count="3"> 

<test name="REgressionSuite"  group-by-instances="true">

    <classes>
    <class name="cli.test1" /> 
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of the how you can do it parallel, you may change the driver instantiation method as you like. Try this and then make adjustment in your code accordingly, It will open two chromes and search for test item in them and will not concatenate.

```
package Grid
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test1 {

    DesiredCapabilities caps;



    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("@BeforeMethod: The annotated method will be run before each test method.");
        caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

    }

    @Test
    public void testing() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),caps);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]")).sendKeys("Testing");
        System.out.println("This is current Url " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        driver.quit();

    }

    @Test
    public void NotTesting() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),caps);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]")).sendKeys("Not Testing");
        System.out.println("This is current Url " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        driver.quit();

    }


    }
```

testng.xml file (same as you have edit package name)

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Regression Suite" verbose="1" parallel="methods" thread-count="4"> 

<test name="REgressionSuite">

    <classes>
    <class name="Grid.test1" /> 
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: HI PJAutomator,
Created new instance of  driver for each test case in @BeforeTest. But still having the same issue.

Comment: @MSohaibKhan can you paste jenkinHub as well ?

Comment: @ PJAutomator. Just added the jenkinHub as well.

Comment: @MSohaibKhan I have pasted an example. Please use that and then adjust your code accordingly,

Comment: @MSohaibKhan , I am getting the same issue. Have you found any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because your `driver` is class level field. When first test method initializes it(`driver = jenkinHub.hub()`) and tries to use it, another method reassigns to it new value, so all your actions are done with the same `WebDriver` instance.
Try to move it in test method like this

```
@Test
public void test() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = jenkinHub.hub(); // create WebDriver instance

    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]")).sendKeys("Testing");
    System.out.println("This is current Url " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
    Thread.sleep(9000);
    driver.quit();

}

@Test
public void NotTesting() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = jenkinHub.hub(); // create another WebDriver instance

    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]")).sendKeys("Not Testing");
    System.out.println("This is current Url " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
    Thread.sleep(9000);
    driver.quit();

}
```